# Proving a dimension inequality about two subspaces, one contained in the other.

Tags: linear-algebra

I have been asked to show the following:

> Let $V$ and $W$ be subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $V\subseteq W$. Prove that $\dim(V)\leq \dim(W)$.

Can I say that since $V$ is less than $W$, that also means that $\dim(V)$ is less than $\dim(W)$ by definition of subspace? This is the only step I have so far.

Answer (score 1):

If $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis of $V$, then $\mathcal{B}$ is a linearly independent subset of $W$. Hence $\dim W\ge|\mathcal{B}|=\dim V$.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both are finite dimensional:

let B be a basis for V.

if B is a basis for W then we are done.

If not add vectors to B until we have a basis in W.

This relies somewhat on the fact that if W is a finite dimensional vector space, then any linearly independent set of vectors from W has a lesser or equal dimension than the basis of W.